# Extracting a character from a string entered by a user

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to remove the first character of a string that is entered by a user. I've tried using a few different things but haven't figured out anything that works. So for example if I have

var userText = prompt("Enter text")l

Say the user enters their name "Billy" ... How can I make userText = "illy"

Comment: you know about the `.substring(start [, optional end])` function, right?

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: I do, but from what I understand it functions similar to the slice function? I'm new to this. But since it's a text entered by a user, I never know how long the text will be and therefor don't know the parameters of where to slice out the text.

Answer (score 1):

Using String.prototype.substring(). For example:

```
var newText = userText.substring(1);
```